# Subsequent switch between remote branches, tracked by git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm with git-svn on top of a customers SVN branch ('trunk')

trunk -> master -> feature

Simplified workflow is:

```
master: git-svn rebase
git rebase master feature [working here...]
git checkout master
git merge feature
git svn-dcommit
```

Now, the customer would like to have my work on an up to now non-existing svn branch ('feature_svn'). 'feature' progressed a lot and hasn't been dcommited for a while. The customer would likely avoid having these developments in his trunk for the moment.

What would be the best way to migrate my work? Can I simply track 'feature_svn' with a new git branch (say 'track_feature_svn'), merge/rebase(?) 'feature' into 'track_feature_svn' and dcommit the result to 'feature_svn'. Are there any possible pitfalls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
git checkout trunk
#will create branch in svn and git, based on currently tracked svn branch (trunk I assume)
git svn branch feature_svn
git rebase feature_svn feature
git svn dcommit
```

You may work with the `feature_svn` branch the same way you worked with trunk. Would expect no major issues as long as you favor rebases over merges.